# Modx Revo: Moving Server, PHP Errors Everywhere

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to move my Revo site to a subdirectory on another server. The issue I have, and I have never had this problem when moving to the root of a domain, is that lots of my extras break terribly! I get the following error above the manager window whenever I click on a resource with a MIGX Tv entry:

```
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /home/content/html/tiesrev/core/components/migx/elements/tv/input/migx.class.php on line 98
(not the full URL for security purposes)
```

On the front end:

Missing arguments for mxCalendar (properly renders but with two of these warnings above it):

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for mxCalendars::addShadowBox(), called in /home/content//html/tiesrev/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/50.include.cache.php on line 199 and defined in /home/content/html/tiesrev/core/components/mxcalendars/model/mxcalendars/mxcalendars.class.php on line 157
```

and DOZENS of these for spiefeed:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/content/html/tiesrev/core/components/spiefeed/includes/simplepie/simplepie.inc on line 738
```

I did a proper move to the server (ensuring .htaccess pointed to subdirectory) like I always have when moving a site to the root. I have NEVER had an issue moving servers but this is my first time moving to a subdirectory with a separate modx revo install in the root. I even did it again, but by doing a clean install, installing the extras in the clean install, then overwritting the database. Same results exactly.

I'm on a godaddy shared server.

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm completely stumped! Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mechanisms at work here: the **version of PHP installed** on your new server is more recent than the version on your old server, and certain functions in use within your application have been **deprecated.**

**Deprecation** means that the functions will be changed or removed in a future version of PHP, and as a result PHP generates warnings now so that you know to take the proper action (in this case, that probably means upgrading your CMS as well.

The other factor is **error reporting,** which was likely disabled on your old host. With error reporting off, none of these issues will generate errors or notices - for now. [You can read about disabling them here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), but I'd recommend you use that as a temporary measure until you can update MODX to the latest version.

Comment: The issue is Modx IS the most recent version and I have never had issues installing into the root of a godaddy shared server before, and very recently with the same extras. Thats what is completely stumping me.

Comment: It may be the newest at the moment, but it probably doesn't support PHP 5.4 or 5.3 or something. Regardless, disabling error reporting will sort it out for now.

Comment: A surprising amount of CMSes and frameworks don't properly support the current version of PHP.

Comment: But why would installing into a subdomain cause any issues vs the root? That is the ONLY difference between this install and previous on the same godaddy servers.

Comment: modx 2.2.4 works perfectly fine on php 5.3 - these are your extras throwing the errors - if you have not updated them, do so. Also I notice one of the pages are being called from cache... delete all the files in your core/cache/ directory.

Comment: @Benjamin: **Because the error reporting settings are different.** You will likely find that error reporting is disabled in the subdirectory.

Comment: So I cant disable error reporting on the godaddy shared server, told me themselves and I tried the oho5.ini. I was able to remove the syntax errors and eliminated the depreciated problems... but the Missing Argument issue is till there and I have no idea how to fix it. The argument is caed like this:

public function addShadowBox($initialWidth,$initialHeight)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently updated [spieFeed (1.6.0-pl)](http://modx.com/extras/package/spiefeed) to include the newer version of the SimplePie (ver. 1.3) which has fixed this particular problem
Try to update with it.

Cheers.